# Installation of package "~/cghseg_0.0.1.tar.gz" had non-zero exit status

Tags: compiler-errors, package, installation, rstudio, centos7

I'm working with Rstudio version:

```
platform       x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu          
version.string R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
```

"CGHSEG" is an old package but is necessary to work with the HOMER.R function for a research but when i tried to install it manually with **install.packages("~/cghseg.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")** but i got a message error.

```
make: *** [helperfuncs.o] Error 1
**`ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘cghseg`’**
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/cghseg’

Warning message:

In install.packages("~/guisseppe/cghseg_0.0.1.tar.gz",  :
installation of package ‘~/guisseppe/Downloads/cghseg_0.0.1.tar.gz’ 
had non-zero exit status**
```

I have tried installing with devtools::install_local and also from the direct url (https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/cghseg/) but  i got this message too.

```
make: *** [helperfuncs.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘cghseg’
* removing ‘/home/guisseppe/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library
/3.6/cghseg’
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from URL:
(converted from warning) installation of package
‘/tmp/Rtmpfy6ldRfile120c16998f92/cghseg_0.0.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit
 status
```

I have tried to install also some libraries on centos 7 like "libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dev" but nothing

Not too sure on how to proceed from here.

Comment: The actual build error is somewhere in the 10-20 lines before the messages you posted.

Comment: @Mat which line .. i just edit some and reposted now.